# Why won't this compile on my schools unix system?

Tags: c++, unix, g++

I finished an assignment that worked fine on my compiler at home, but when I uploaded it to the schools linux system I can't get it to compile.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Set.cpp: In destructor ‘Set::~Set()’:
Set.cpp:42:1: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
Set.cpp:55:1: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
Set.cpp:67:1: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
Set.cpp:193:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

I'm not exactly sure whats going on here, but my program compiles just fine in codeblocks.

```
#include "Set.h"
Set::Set()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        bitString[i] = 0;
}


Set::Set(const Set& s)
{
}



Set::~Set()
{






//Functions for modifying the sets individually:





void Set::add(int i)
{
    unsigned int mask;
    int bit, word;

    word = i / 32;
    bit = i % 32;
    mask = 1 << bit;
    bitString[word] |= mask;
}



void Set::remove(int i)
{
    unsigned int mask;
    int bit, word;

    word = i / 32;
    mask = (1 << (i % 32)) ;
    bitString[word] &= ~(mask);
}



int Set::size()
{
    unsigned size = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < 32; ++x)
        {
            if (bitString[i] & (1 << x))
                ++size;
        }
    }
    cout << "Size of this set is: " << size << endl;
    return size;
}



int Set::is_member(int i)

{
    int bit, word;

    word = i / 32;
    bit = i % 32;

    if((bitString[word] >> bit) & 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}







//Operators Defined here:








void Set::operator=(const Set& s)
{
    int bits;
    for (bits = 0; bits <= 3; bits++)
    {
        bitString[bits] = s.bitString[bits];
    }
}

Set Set::operator-(const Set& s)
{
    Set result;
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        result.bitString[x] = (bitString[x] & ~s.bitString[x]);
    }
    return result;
}

Set Set::operator&(const Set& s)
{
    Set result;
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        result.bitString[x] = (bitString[x] & s.bitString[x]);
    }
    return result;
}



Set Set::operator|(const Set& s)
{
    Set result;
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        result.bitString[x] = (bitString[x] | s.bitString[x]);
    }

    return result;
}


// XOR
Set Set::operator^(const Set& s)
{
    Set result;
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        result.bitString[x] = (bitString[x] ^ s.bitString[x]);
    }
    return result;
}



// Print Result
void Set::printSet()

{
    unsigned size = 0;

    cout << "Set:  { \b";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < 32; ++x)
        {
            if (bitString[i] & (1 << x))
                cout << (x + (i * 32)) << ",";
        }
    }
    cout << "\b}" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a `}` for the destructor.

Comment: Thanks, such a silly error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in the following code:

```
#include "Set.h"
Set::Set()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        bitString[i] = 0;
}

Set::Set(const Set& s)
{
}

Set::~Set()
{
```

Here in the destructor you forgot to close the parenthesis. That's what the compiler is complaining about. It will not run in any system. You modify it as:

```
Set::~Set()
{
}
```